# Gamma and Exponential distribution question?

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function

The working time of one bank has an exponential distribution with a parameter λ=0.1 (in minutes). You came in the bank, but there were already 35 people before you. What's the probability that all of them will be done in 45 minutes?

Comment: Exact answer? Note that the mean is $3.5$ minutes! It would make more sense if the serving time were $1$ minute and not $0.1$.

Comment: Could you please explain how you would solve this? (even though it makes no sense)

Comment: The example is like this: 
these are the work times of 10 people: 7.4 , 7.5 ,  8.5,  29.2,  5.5,  21.6,  4.3,  8.1,  5.3,  1.7;;

μ1 = EX = 1/λ and m1=9.91 (the average of these numbers);;
so μ1=m1, that is λ=1/9.91, and that is 0.1

Comment: Then $\lambda = 0.1$ is not in minutes. Do not confuse the *rate* (people per minute) with the mean of Exponential distribution (minutes).

Comment: I used the method of moments to find  λ.
So how much is  λ?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to *Poisson process* (look it up). The probability that they will be done over time $T$ is the probability that $N \ge 35$ where $N \sim Poisson(\lambda T)$. You can calculate that using software.

Also, you can apply Normal approximation, $Z \approx (N - \lambda T)/\sqrt{\lambda T}$.

Note: here, $\lambda$ is the rate of service (people per minute).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that

$P(X\le 45)=P(\displaystyle\sum_1^kx_i\le45)=Erlang(k,\lambda)=\Gamma(\lambda, k);\,\lambda=0.1,\, k = 35$